# when I uploaded a pdf file with several pages into lyx and used pages=-, it showed just the first pages several times

Tags: graphics, lyx

when I uploaded a pdf file with several pages into lyx and used pages=-, it showed just the first pages several times. I had tried all other option, but i got the same results.....the same first page for x times

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF output should be correct. The LyX preview is incorrect, because of reasons explained [in this trac issue](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9039). Specifically, LyX allows use of an external program to convert the PDF into an image usable for LyX's display. When LyX runs that external command to convert the PDF, it currently just asks for the first page of the PDF. To fix this, we would have to create a new variable that is passed to converters that specifies the page number.